# Firebase - Retrieve custom data by UID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So, I have a list with some users:

[image: image1]

And a custom table with Username and a User UID reference:

[image: image2]

After the user logged in I store his UID in a variable but, what is the correct way to retrieve the userName based on UserUID?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend changing the structure of your database. Instead of using `push()` when you add users to the database, use `setValue()` with the userId as the key and the username as the value:

```
{
    users: {
        EsqhdtziWRPtoNLu485zvg: "Test User 1",
        yBnNVVyHHcfq67ccGABGz2N8R: "Test User 2",
        ...,
        ...
   }
}
```

This makes the username much easier to access.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll fix it.

Comment: helpful for normalize your db... Great one ...!!